# ASP.NET MVC 3 Video.Flash helper not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, youtube, embed, helper

I want to embed some youtube videos at my site using Video.Flash helper.
Microsoft.Web.Helpers is added to the References.

Using

```
@Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash(path: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENf_RJMz2WE")
```

or

```
@Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENf_RJMz2WE")
```

doesn't show anything. Just a blank page. If I right click, the menu says "Movie not loaded".

I have flash player installed correctly, I can see youtube videos..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL you're passing is the full HTML Youtube page rather than the flash video itself. To embed the video youtube uses the URL format `youtube.com/v/{id}` rather than `youtube.com/watch?v={id}`. The correct way would be:

```
@Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash("http://www.youtube.com/v/ENf_RJMz2WE")
```

where `ENf_RJMz2WE` is your video id.

Comment: Where to find that dll when not on razor? `<%:Microsoft.Web.Helpers.Video.Flash("http://www.youtube.com/v/ENf_RJMz2WE") %>`

Comment: Found how to install the package using nuget... `PM> Install-Package microsoft-web-helpers`